# Why C# ASP.NET MVC Code First POCO Classes must have getters and setters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, codefirst, setters, poco

Why in, C# ASP.NET MVC Code First project, POCO Classes must have getters and setters  ( {get; set; } ) in order to work?

```
public float data { get; set; }
```

or in db context class

```
public DbSet<SGD.Models.MyData> MyData{ get; set; }
```

I just don't understand why a simple attribute (without getters and setters) doesn't works.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that's entity framework that requires that, not ASP.net MVC.

Comment: Because they are properties rather than fields. Which means they're internally pairs of methods. That's much easier for a framework to deal with than fields.

Comment: Apparently the EF authors decided to only support properties and not fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Microsoft decided to only support properties in Entity Framework.

There are [many reasons why properties are preferred over public fields](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx), but I'll just mention the one that I think is most relevant here:  changing from public fields to properties (if the need arises) is a *binary breaking change.*